# 'Unknown Identity' Blackbox quest solution?

Tags: black-box

What is the solution to the **Unknown identity** quest in the BLACKBOX Student Dev Challenge?

I've been developing a quest for the CTF challenge, and seem to have forgotten the solution. If anyone remembers it, please reply with it.

If I remember it, I'll answer it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Oh... I remembered.

The solution is *youpassbutter99*